# Dell Vostro 14 3446: Trackpad detected as Mouse (or something else)

Tags: dell, touchpad, synaptics, alps

For some reason, my trackpad is being detected as mouse in all the distro that I tried (Ubuntu 14.04, Linux Mint 17, Crunchbang, Salix) except Ubuntu 12.04. Here is the relevant output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    25.350] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL0662:00 06CB:2985 (/dev/input/event13)
[    25.350] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    25.350] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'DLL0662:00 06CB:2985'
[    25.350] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: always reports core events
[    25.350] (**) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Device: "/dev/input/event13"
[    25.351] (--) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x2985
[    25.351] (--) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    25.351] (--) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Found relative axes
[    25.351] (--) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Found x and y relative axes
[    25.351] (II) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: Configuring as mouse
[    25.351] (**) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    25.351] (**) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    25.351] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/INT33C3:00/i2c-11/i2c-DLL0662:00/input/input13/event13"
[    25.351] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLL0662:00 06CB:2985" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[    25.351] (II) evdev: DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: initialized for relative axes.
[    25.351] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    25.351] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    25.351] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    25.351] (**) DLL0662:00 06CB:2985: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    25.351] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL0662:00 06CB:2985 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    25.351] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    25.351] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?

PS. Dell has provided some sort of driver at http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverid=5V4HN but the installation fails both on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 with this message:

```
(Reading database ... 147284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics-dkms_0.1_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics-dkms (0.1) over (0.1) ...
Setting up oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics-dkms (0.1) ...
Loading new oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics-0.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-24-generic
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-24-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

`/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/make.log` contains the following:

```
DKMS make.log for oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics-0.1 for kernel 3.13.0-24-generic (amd64)
Fri Sep 12 01:18:44 UTC 2014
make: Entering directory `/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build'
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/appletouch.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/bcm5974.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.o
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:49:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gpio_mouse_probe’
  static int __devinit gpio_mouse_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
                  ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:153:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gpio_mouse_remove’
 static int __devexit gpio_mouse_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
                  ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:174:12: error: ‘gpio_mouse_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .probe  = gpio_mouse_probe,
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:175:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-    declaration]
  .remove  = __devexit_p(gpio_mouse_remove),
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:175:25: error: ‘gpio_mouse_remove’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .remove  = __devexit_p(gpio_mouse_remove),
                     ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.c:23:13: warning: ‘gpio_mouse_scan’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void gpio_mouse_scan(struct input_polled_dev *dev)
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build/gpio_mouse.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/var/lib/dkms/oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics/0.1/build'
```

Thanks

Comment: U got any solution?? facing same issue.using Vostro 14 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in kernel, the `3.13.0-37-generic` kernel seems to solve it (at least for this touchpad).